# How to manage common code base for android and ios in svn?

Tags: svn, cordova

How to manage common code base for android and ios in svn? am new to svn, can suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the svn:externals

You have a unique source copy and the other copies are a shortcut to the same repository.
- You can commit from any place that commits to the same origin
- All copies get notified of changes in update sync

I give you a image of an example viewed in Tortoise.

[image]